# dotnet core cpu utilization changed dramatically after upgrading to 2.1

Tags: .net-core

This might not be an issue necessarily, it might actually be a good thing, but looking at the chart below you can probably see where we upgraded to 2.1 from 2.0. CPU usage has on average gone up, and it is much peakier.

Any recommendations? this is across the board for ~15 services.

[cpu utilization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmcAk.png)

Comment: Same issue here, do you run your application in a container ?

Comment: yes, in docker on ECS

Comment: docker swarm here also. It could be also the issue they solved in 2.1 with the detection of the memory and cpu allocated in the container, that is not working in 2.0. So the garbage collection is called more often.

Comment: Do you have any links to the issue they solved in 2.1? This could be it, but I'm not finding anything when I search.

Comment: yes: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/13489

Answer (score 1):

After few investigations, it seems that the new aspnetcore 2.1 Kestrel transportation lib, called "Socket" generate a lot of CPU stress. I resolved the issue by following the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.1#transport-configuration

the result:

[image]